# Python: CMake error when installing face_recognition

Tags: python, numpy, scope, cmake, scipy

I'm trying to install face_recognition and have already installed dlib, CMake, numpy, scipy and Boost. However when I run

```
pip install face_recognition
```

I get this error:

```
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake c:\Users\Julian\Desktop\deepfakes-master\dlib-master\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=c:\Users\Julian\Desktop\deepfakes-master\dlib-master\build\lib.win32-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=yes -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=c:\Users\Julian\Desktop\deepfakes-master\dlib-master\build\lib.win32-3.6'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/deepfakes-master/dlib-master/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/deepfakes-master/dlib-master/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I don't have much of an idea what this means. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have installed a C++ compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download the .whl package of dlib](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/)  of your version of python **note** the minimum is 19.7

[Download the latest version of cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) for your version of windows.
When installing cmake make sure that you **tick** the option to add it to the system path.

Finally `pip install face_recognition`